# Comandos no Barchart do software R

Tags: r

Como faço para usar alguns comandos como `font.main`, `col.main` dentro do comando `barchart` do pacote `lattice`. Estou tentando usar esses comandos e não estão funcionando.

Answer (score 2):

Os argumentos `font.main` e `col.main` não são utilizados dentro da função `lattice::barchart`. Eles são reservados para os gráficos padrão do `R`. Entretanto, é possível alterar as características do título de um gráfico do pacote `lattice` utilizando uma lista de opções.

Por exemplo, ao rodar o comando

```
barchart(VADeaths, main = list(label = "Teste", col = "Pink", font = 3))
```

eu obtenho o gráfico a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bastou definir uma lista para o parâmetro `main` com o título (`label`), cor (`col`) e tipo de fonte (`font`) para alterar os parâmetros desejados no gráfico.

#### *Resposta original, antes do comentário do AP*

`font.main` e `col.main` não são argumentos para serem utilizados dentro do comando `barplot`. Eles são parâmetros gráficos e devem ser utilizados dentro do comando `par`, responsável por estas configurações.

Por exemplo, veja o que ocorre ao rodar o comando abaixo:

```
barplot(VADeaths, main="Death Rates in Virginia (1940)")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas eu posso definir outros parâmetros para a fonte se eu rodar a função `par` anteriormente:

```
par(font.main=3, col.main="pink")
barplot(VADeaths, main="Death Rates in Virginia (1940)")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Recomendo testar diferentes opções de `font.main` para ver qual te agrada mais ou procurar na internet uma lista com elas.

Para ver quais são as outras opções de personalização possíveis para os gráficos, digite `?par` no console do `R`.

A vantagem de utilizar a função `par` para isso é que as suas configurações vão valer para gráficos de barra, histogramas, boxplots e tudo o mais que o `R` for capaz de produzir com seus gráficos padrão.

Comment: Bom dia Marcus. Como faço para usar esses comandos no barchart comando do pacote lattice?

Comment: Resposta editada. Da próxima vez, [guia de postagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R, de modo que ela fique o menos ambígua possível.